# keydown event listener for spacebar

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I worked on a mini project that works when I click on the mouse the screen populates with numerous circles with each click. I am trying to do the same thing, however, the difference is when the spacebar is pushed for it to do the same thing.

For some reason the code I have is not working I am even console logging and see nothing and I do not understand why. Some guidance would be appreciated.

Here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>CircleMaker</title>
    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

    <div id="ball"></div>

</body>


    <script src="mainn.js"></script>
</html>
```

css

```
html{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *::before, *::after{
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

#ball{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    top: 200px;
    left: 200px;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 100px;
}
```

Javascript

```
var circle = document.getElementById('ball'); 

circle.addEventListener('keydown', circleMultiplier);

function circleMultiplier(e){
    e.preventDefault();

 console.log(e.keyCode);

    if (e.key === 32){

   var divsize = ((Math.random()*100) + 50).toFixed();
    var color = '#'+ Math.round(0xffffff * Math.random()).toString(16);
    var posx = (Math.random() * (document.body.clientWidth - divsize).toFixed());
    var posy = (Math.random() * (document.body.clientWidth - divsize).toFixed());
   var newDiv = document.createElement('div');



   newDiv.style.cssText = 'top:'+posx+'px; left:'+posy+'px; position:absolute; width: 200px; height: 200px;background-color:' +color+ '; border-radius: 100px;';


    document.body.appendChild(newDiv);

    } 

}
```

When I hit the spacebar it should populate like the following image:

[image: final]

This code works for when I click the mouse:

```
var circle = document.getElementById('ball'); 

circle.addEventListener('click', circleMultiplier);

function circleMultiplier(){
    var divsize = ((Math.random()*100) + 50).toFixed();
    var color = '#'+ Math.round(0xffffff * Math.random()).toString(16);
    var posx = (Math.random() * (document.body.clientWidth - divsize).toFixed());
    var posy = (Math.random() * (document.body.clientWidth - divsize).toFixed());
    var newDiv = document.createElement('div');



    newDiv.style.cssText = 'top:'+posx+'px; left:'+posy+'px; position:absolute; width: 200px; height: 200px;background-color:' +color+ '; border-radius: 100px;';


    document.body.appendChild(newDiv);



}
```

Comment: Shouldnt you check `e.keyCode` instead of `e.key`?

Answer (score 1):

You can not listen to a keyboard event on a div. The click is happening on the div itself so it executes the corresponding callback function.

For your use case it makes more sense to attach the listener it the document itself.
For example.

```
document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){console.log(e.keyCode)});
```

Comment: This isn't entirely true. You can set a [tabindex attribute](https://developer.paciellogroup.com/blog/2014/08/using-the-tabindex-attribute/) on the div to make it select-able with the keyboard. But this is certainly the issue the poster is running into. Try attaching the event listener to the document body instead of the div.